# Конструкция switch-case работает не правильно

Tags: php, switch

Уважаемые знатоки!

имеется такая конструкция:

```
//Страницы сайта
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'error';

switch($page){
    //Home page
    case 'home':
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/page/home.php');
        break;
    //Страница услуг
    case 'services':
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/page/service.php');
        break;
    //Страница ошибок
    case 'error':
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/page/error.php');
        break;
    //Home page (default)
    default:
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/page/home.php');
        break;
        exit();
}
```

этот код расположен в файле index.php в корневом каталоге. По идеи, при открытии файла index.php - должна инклюдиться default файл home.php - но почему-то выдает error.php (открывается файл error.php) что здесь написано неверно? поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: адрес у вас открыт типа такого `mysite.ru?p=` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, другие страницы открываю таким путем /?p=services  и т.д.

Comment: Я не про другие страницы....на главной присутствует этот параметр или нет?... если нет то у вас `p` в гет запросе не существует....соответственно в условии `$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'error';`  переменной присваивается значение `error`.... а дальше в `case` согласно правилу туда и попадает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема, здесь, разумеется, не в операторе switch/case, а в логике человека, писашвего код.

Вот здесь

```
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'error';
```

буквально написано

> при открытии файла index.php без параметров должна инклюдиться **error.php**

что несколько противоречит заявленным желаниям.

чтобы открывалась по умолчанию домашняя страница, а для несуществующих страниц - ошибка, то надо сделать так

```
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'home';

switch($page){
    //Home page
    case 'home':
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/page/home.php');
        break;
    //Страница услуг
    case 'services':
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/page/service.php');
        break;
    //Страница ошибок
    default:
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/page/error.php');
        break;
}
```

Вообще, слово default довольно интересное. Казалось бы, какая связь между "дефолт" (банкротство) и "default" (значение по умолчанию)? А вот как раз правильный перевод и расставляет все по местам: default - это, условно говоря, нехватка, недостача. А "by default", соответственно - "за неимением других вариантов", "если ни один вариант не подошел".

То есть в данном случае дефолтной страницей должна быть именно error.php

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я так сильно сейчас искал видео урок - где узнал вообще об switch/case - вот в том видео уроке я узнал о таком коде. Логики, конечно я не понимаю, честно говоря, я только начинаю изучать PHP.